# Prolog. Nodes of a Binary Tree

Tags: tree, prolog

Im new using Prolog and I wish you could help me.

I need to get all nodes in a binary tree with a predicate called `listofnodes(A4,L)`. The tree `A4` is made like this:

```
[[[[[],1,[]],5,[]],
7,
[[],3,[[],4,[]]]],
6,
[[[],10,[]],
8,
[[[],9,[]],11,[[],2,[]]]]]
```

And has this form

[image]

Ok. Thats sounds easy but I need to make the predicate only using these constructors and selectors:

```
empty([]).
root([_,N,_], N). %root node
hi([HI,_,_],HI).  %left child
hd([_,_,HD],HD).  %right child
dotree(R,HI,HD,[HI,R,HD]). %make a tree
```

So I think I could do this with the next code but Its wrong

```
childs(X,[L,X,R],[L,X,R]).
childs(X,[L,_,_],D) :- childs(X,L,D).
childs(X,[_,_,R],D) :- childs(X,R,D).

listofnodes([],[]).
listofnodes([[],X,[]],[X]).
listofnodes(Abn,P) :- raiz(Abn, N), childs(N,Abn,D), listofnodes(D,P).
```

Any ideas how can I resolve this ?

Thanks !

Comment: What is `raiz/2`?

Comment: But what is the order of the nodes in the list, and why are you using such strange nested lists tree instead of normal `tree/3` tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably don't need `listofnodes([[],X,[]],[X]).` if you define your recursive case properly. You already have `listofnodes([], []).` which properly defines what the list of nodes looks like for an empty tree.

Think about what the rule might be for a list of nodes in the general case:

> The list of nodes for a tree, `[Left, Node, Right]` would be the list of nodes for `Left`, the node `Node`, and the list of nodes from `Right`.

So your predicate should resemble this rule somehow.

```
listofnodes([Left, Node, Right], ListOfNodes) :-
    listofnodes(Left, LeftNodes),
    ...
```

I'll leave the rest as an exercise.

Comment: Thanks ! Really useful :)